# Xcode C++ Error "linker command failed with exit code 1"

Tags: c++, xcode, compiler-errors

I am a beginning programming student.

Here I have written a simple "sum of two numbers" program in Xcode using C++.

```
//preprocessor directive
#include <stdio.h>

//local declarations

int main (void)
{
//declare variables
int n1, n2, sum;

//input prompts
printf("This program finds the sum of two numbers. Enter your first number.\n");
scanf("%d" , &n1);

printf("Enter another number.\n");
scanf("%d" , &n2);

//process
sum=n1+n2;

//output
printf("The sum is %d." , sum);

return 0;

}
```

As far as I can tell, my syntax is accurate, however, when I try to build the program, I get this error code:

"Apple Mach-O Linker (Id) Error. Linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)"

I have been unable to solve this by reading other Q's and A's.

Any proposed solution? It would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: That can't be the only error, there must be more before it.

Answer (score 1):

Your error is incomplete. You need to use `-v` to see invocation (as suggested) or you need to check your log for more details as the error '*Linker command failed with exit code 1*' is usually followed by the more detailed error.

So to find more details, in Xcode click on the error under *Buildtime* and choose *Reveal in log*. This should give you extra hint. Without any specific error, it's difficult to know what's the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This error is normally displayed if you have other errors in your source code. If you copy pasted the code directly, there is an `x` before the opening brace in main.

Comment: okay. thanks. the "x" before opening brace was just a copying error, not in the code I tried to compile.

Comment: Then there must be some other error - what is showed in Issue Navigator?

Comment: The Issue Navigator says "one issue." - "Apple Mach-O Linker (Id) Error - Linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)"